# Reversing the order of integration. (Picture included)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I wish to reverse the order of integration.

So, I think the original integration is over the region above.

So, reversing the order of integration, I split it into two cases.

First region (from 0 to 1) comes first, then second region (from -1/2 to 0) comes next.

But, I get the wrong answer.

Where did I make a mistake?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that when $x < 0$, the integral $$\int_{y=0}^x e^{-y^2} \, dy = - \int_{y=x}^0 e^{-y^2} \, dy,$$ thus this area is **negative**.  If you simply take the difference of the two double integrals you wrote on the right-hand side, rather than the sum, you would obtain the correct result.

---

$$\int_{x=-1/2}^1 \int_{y=0}^x f(x,y) \, dy \, dx = \int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=y}^1 f(x,y) \, dx \, dy - \int_{y=-1/2}^0 \int_{x=-1/2}^y f(x,y) \, dx \, dy.$$  Again, the negative sign is necessary because for $x < 0$, the inner integral on the LHS is **REVERSED**.

Comment: But, this question is "evaluate the integral" not "find area" Isn't it the case that I should change the sign when asked to find the area ?

Comment: You have not understood my comment.  See the revised answer.